# Gremlin: getting empty result for union using identity

Tags: gremlin

I'm executing the following query which returns an empty list:

```
g
  .V("user-11")
  .outE("validate_phone")
  .union(__.identity(), __.V().hasId("phone-29e78c7c18a8bb33c608dbc233bc155e"))    
  .toList()
```

Which is strange, since `phone-29e78c7c18a8bb33c608dbc233bc155e` is a valid node in the graph.

Trying to figure out the issue I realized that node `user-11` has no edge `validate_phone` which would seem to cause the problem, I tried with a different node for which the `identity()` function would result in a non-empty list, and found that in that case `v[phone-29e78c7c18a8bb33c608dbc233bc155e]` is returned.

In other words

```
g.V("user-11").outE("validate_phone").toList() // returns an empty list
g.V("user-347883719").outE("validate_phone").toList() // returns a non empty list
```

and

```
g.V("user-347883719").outE("validate_phone").union(__.identity(), __.V().hasId("phone-29e78c7c18a8bb33c608dbc233bc155e")).toList() // works just fine
g.V("user-11").outE("validate_phone").union(__.identity(), __.V().hasId("phone-29e78c7c18a8bb33c608dbc233bc155e")).toList() // should return at least one vertex, but doesn't
```

My first thought is that ether `union` or `identity` don't behave as expected when merging empty query results, but I may be missing something.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps if you picture Gremlins executing your traversal steps.

Here is why the following traversal is not returning any results.

```
g.V("user-11").outE("validate_phone").union(__.identity(), __.V().hasId("phone-29e78c7c18a8bb33c608dbc233bc155e"))
```

`g.V("user-11")` places a Gremlin on v[user-11]
`outE("validate_phone")` asks this Gremlin to move to the outgoing "validate_phone" edge. And since the current vertex does not have an outgoing "validate_phone" edge, the Gremlin cannot execute the step and dies.
There are no Gremlins remaining to execute the `union` step. So the traversal returns an empty result.

Your other traversal

```
g.V("user-347883719").outE("validate_phone").union(__.identity(), __.V().hasId("phone-29e78c7c18a8bb33c608dbc233bc155e"))
```

does return a result because the Gremlin can execute the `outE` step and does not die.

Here is a traversal that will always return a result regardless whether your user vertex has an outgoing "validate_phone" edge or not.

```
g.V("user-11").union(__.outE("validate_phone"), __.V().hasId("phone-29e78c7c18a8bb33c608dbc233bc155e"))
```

`g.V("user-11")` places a Gremlin on v[user-11]
The `union` step asks this Gremlin to spawn two child Gremlins.
The first child Gremlin will execute the first nested traversal `outE("validate_phone")`. And will either return the edge if it exists or die.
The second child Gremlin will execute the nested traversal `V().hasId("phone-29e78c7c18a8bb33c608dbc233bc155e")` which will return the phone vertex.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense and actually helped me to understand and refactor my code, thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks @MarceloRydel ! Please remember to mark my post as the answer.